I try integration custom model tflite to android but have error : Error getting native address of native library: task_vision_jni_gms
in here i try integration custom model to realtime detection sign language using kotlin, library CameraX and tflite but have some error like this
Error getting native address of native library: task_vision_jni_gms (Ask Gemini)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred when initializing ImageClassifier: Input tensor has type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions metadata to preprocess input images.
at org.tensorflow.lite.task.gms.vision.classifier.ImageClassifier.initJniWithModelFdAndOptions(Native Method)

this my code model before convert to .tflite
TRAIN_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'train')
VAL_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'val')
TEST_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test')

IMAGE_SIZE = (150, 150)
BATCH_SIZE = 32

train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR,
    labels='inferred',
    class_names=None,
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    image_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    label_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True,
)

val_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    VAL_DIR,
    labels='inferred',
    class_names=None,
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    image_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    label_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True,
)

test_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    TEST_DIR,
    labels='inferred',
    class_names=None,
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    image_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    label_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True,
)

# Lanjutkan dengan normalisasi dataset
normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 100
PREFETCH_BUFFER_SIZE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_dataset_prepared = (train_dataset
                       .shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE)
                       .cache()
                       .prefetch(PREFETCH_BUFFER_SIZE)
                       )

val_dataset_prepared = (val_dataset
                      .shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE)
                      .cache()
                      .prefetch(PREFETCH_BUFFER_SIZE)
                    )

test_dataset_prepared = (test_dataset
                      .cache()
                      .prefetch(PREFETCH_BUFFER_SIZE)
                    )
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam

#Mendefinisikan CNN Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + (3,))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#Output
model.add(Dense(26, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=Adam(0.0001),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.summary()
training_history = model.fit (
    train_dataset_prepared,
    validation_data = val_dataset_prepared,
    epochs=50
)
# Evaluasi model dengan dataset test
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_dataset_prepared)

print(f"Test loss: {test_loss}")
print(f"Test accuracy: {test_accuracy}")
# Simpan model TFLite ke file
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model) 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open('trained_model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model

this my code helper for image classification
package com.example.isyara.util

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Build
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Surface
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import com.example.isyara.R
import com.google.android.gms.tflite.client.TfLiteInitializationOptions
import com.google.android.gms.tflite.gpu.support.TfLiteGpu
import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType
import org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.CompatibilityList
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.ops.CastOp
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.ops.NormalizeOp
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ImageProcessor
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.ResizeOp
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.BaseOptions
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.vision.ImageProcessingOptions
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.gms.vision.TfLiteVision
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.gms.vision.classifier.Classifications
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.gms.vision.classifier.ImageClassifier

class ImageClassifierHelper(
    var threshold: Float = 0.7f,
    var maxResults: Int = 1,
    val modelName: String = "model.tflite",
    val context: Context,
    val classifierListener: ClassifierListener?
) {
    private var imageClassifier: ImageClassifier? = null

    init {
        TfLiteGpu.isGpuDelegateAvailable(context).onSuccessTask { gpuAvailable ->
            val optionsBuilder = TfLiteInitializationOptions.builder()
            if (gpuAvailable) {
                optionsBuilder.setEnableGpuDelegateSupport(true)
            }
            TfLiteVision.initialize(context, optionsBuilder.build())
        }.addOnSuccessListener {
            setupImageClassifier()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            classifierListener?.onError(context.getString(R.string.tflitevision_is_not_initialized_yet))
        }
    }

    private fun setupImageClassifier() {
        val optionsBuilder = ImageClassifier.ImageClassifierOptions.builder()
            .setScoreThreshold(threshold)
            .setMaxResults(maxResults)

        val baseOptionsBuilder = BaseOptions.builder()

        if (CompatibilityList().isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice) {
            baseOptionsBuilder.useGpu()
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            baseOptionsBuilder.useNnapi()
        } else {
            // Menggunakan CPU
            baseOptionsBuilder.setNumThreads(4)
        }

        optionsBuilder.setBaseOptions(baseOptionsBuilder.build())

        try {
            imageClassifier = ImageClassifier.createFromFileAndOptions(
                context,
                modelName,
                optionsBuilder.build()
            )
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            classifierListener?.onError(context.getString(R.string.image_classifier_failed))
            Log.e(TAG, e.message.toString())
        }
    }

    fun classifyImage(image: ImageProxy) {

        if (!TfLiteVision.isInitialized()) {
            val errorMessage = context.getString(R.string.tflitevision_is_not_initialized_yet)
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)
            classifierListener?.onError(errorMessage)
            return
        }

        if (imageClassifier == null) {
            setupImageClassifier()
        }

        val imageProcessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
            .add(ResizeOp(150, 150, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
            .add(CastOp(DataType.FLOAT32))
            .add(NormalizeOp(0f, 1f))
            .build()

        val tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(TensorImage.fromBitmap(toBitmap(image)))

        val imageProcessingOptions = ImageProcessingOptions.builder()
            .setOrientation(getOrientationFromRotation(image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees))
            .build()

        var inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        val results = imageClassifier?.classify(tensorImage, imageProcessingOptions)
        inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - inferenceTime
        classifierListener?.onResults(
            results,
            inferenceTime
        )
    }

    private fun toBitmap(image: ImageProxy): Bitmap {
        val bitmapBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            image.width,
            image.height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        image.use { bitmapBuffer.copyPixelsFromBuffer(image.planes[0].buffer) }
        image.close()
        return bitmapBuffer
    }

    private fun getOrientationFromRotation(rotation: Int): ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation {
        return when (rotation) {
            Surface.ROTATION_270 -> ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.BOTTOM_RIGHT
            Surface.ROTATION_180 -> ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            Surface.ROTATION_90 -> ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.TOP_LEFT
            else -> ImageProcessingOptions.Orientation.RIGHT_TOP
        }
    }

    interface ClassifierListener {
        fun onError(error: String)
        fun onResults(
            results: List<Classifications>?,
            inferenceTime: Long
        )
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "ImageClassifierHelper"
    }
}

this my activity code using that helper
package com.example.isyara.ui.translate


import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.WindowInsets
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.core.resolutionselector.AspectRatioStrategy
import androidx.camera.core.resolutionselector.ResolutionSelector
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import com.example.isyara.R
import com.example.isyara.databinding.ActivityTranslateBinding
import com.example.isyara.util.ImageClassifierHelper
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.gms.vision.classifier.Classifications
import java.text.NumberFormat
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class TranslateActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityTranslateBinding
    private var cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
    private lateinit var imageClassifierHelper: ImageClassifierHelper


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        binding = ActivityTranslateBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }

    public override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        hideSystemUI()
        startCamera()
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        imageClassifierHelper = ImageClassifierHelper(
            context = this,
            classifierListener = object : ImageClassifierHelper.ClassifierListener {
                override fun onError(error: String) {
                    runOnUiThread {
                        Toast.makeText(this@TranslateActivity, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }

                override fun onResults(results: List<Classifications>?, inferenceTime: Long) {
                    runOnUiThread {
                        results?.let { it ->
                            if (it.isNotEmpty() && it[0].categories.isNotEmpty()) {
                                println(it)
                                val sortedCategories =
                                    it[0].categories.sortedByDescending { it?.score }
                                val displayResult =
                                    sortedCategories.joinToString("\n") {
                                        "${it.label} " + NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()
                                            .format(it.score).trim()
                                    }
                                binding.tvResult.text = displayResult
                            } else {
                                binding.tvResult.text = ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )

        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            val resolutionSelector = ResolutionSelector.Builder()
                .setAspectRatioStrategy(AspectRatioStrategy.RATIO_16_9_FALLBACK_AUTO_STRATEGY)
                .build()
            val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setResolutionSelector(resolutionSelector)
                .setTargetRotation(binding.cameraView.display.rotation)
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
                .build()
            imageAnalyzer.setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) { image ->
                imageClassifierHelper.classifyImage(image)
            }

            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.cameraView.surfaceProvider)
            }
            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this,
                    cameraSelector,
                    preview,
                    imageAnalyzer
                )
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@TranslateActivity,
                    "Gagal memunculkan kamera.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                Log.e(TAG, "startCamera: ${exc.message}")
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun hideSystemUI() {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION") if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
        } else {
            window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            )
        }
        supportActionBar?.hide()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "TranslateActivity"

    }
}

this layout from TranslateActivity
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.translate.TranslateActivity">

    <!-- Lapisan untuk Kamera -->
    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/cameraView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.example.isyara.util.OverlayView
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#BFFFFFFF"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Result" />

    <!-- Tombol Back di Atas -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/backbutton"
        android:contentDescription="@string/back_button"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:elevation="8dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topButtons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomContainer"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

        <Button
            style="@style/RoundedButton"
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:text="@string/tambah"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            style="@style/RoundedButton"
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hapus"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Border di Bagian Bawah -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomBorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/primary" />

    <!-- Container di Bagian Bawah -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomBorder"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="#F9F9F9"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <!-- Kotak Tumpul dengan Teks -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/dummy_text"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!-- Tombol di Sebelahnya -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnAction"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_voice"
                android:contentDescription="@string/voice_button"
                app:tint="#FFFFFF" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

